# Hiding/embedding files inside .exe

Tags: c#, wpf, embedded-resource

I have a `.OCX` file that I use in the system to fix a problem with an application that I use at work. But now, I`m building an application to be able to fix it and publish this file among my colleagues ... I want to make a single `.exe` file that will extract the `.OCX` file to a certain place in the system, overwrite if exists, and then use it as I want to. I want to know how to hide/embed the file in my application and how to extract it to certain location in the system. I want to know also how to call system commands from within my application like regsvr32, ect ...

Comment: Embed it as a resource. Use google on the rest...

Comment: I want it all, I want it all, and I want it now! http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Want_It_All

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: I`ve tried before in another project yet I failed to do it, thats why I`m asking for steps!

Comment: I`ve tried adding a file as a resource, and that I did. But I couldn`t call/use it as found through google. I was using .NET Framework 4 then, but now due to system restrictions, I`m using 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Add the file you would like to extract to your solution. Then right click, press properties and choose "build action" "embedded resource".

This link shows how to access the resource stream from within the exe: [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)

To run an application simply use:

```
Process.Run("regsvr32....");
```